# Spring REST ResponseEntity how to return response when we have two objects

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

`1. For example UserProfile which has 3 properties name,dob, age`
`2. And 2nd class let's say UserProfileResponse which has only "id"`

```
public ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile)
{
      UserProfileResponse userProfileResponse = new UserProfileResponse();
      userProfileResponse.setId(??)  // How do I set ID?
      **createUserProfileData(userProfile)  /// This is used to create DB record** 
      return new ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse>(userProfileResponse,HTTPStatus.OK);  
}
```

So for this `userProfileResponse.setId(??)` how can I set the ID value?
can I directly do like this  `userProfileResponse.setId(userProfileResponse.getId());`

Or I can Pass one more request body like this

```
ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile, @RequestBody ID)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `userProfileResponse.setId(userProfileResponse.getId())` doesn't make any sense. It wouldn't change anything to the response. We don't know, because we have no idea of what this ID in the response is supposed to be . If it's the ID of the user profile that the method creates, assuming that creating a user profile generates its ID, then get it out of the user profile after it has been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `createUserProfileData` method and return the id of the newly inserted object from it.

In `createUserProfileData` method, you can call `saveAndFlush` method of the repository which will save the `userProfile` Object.

This will return the id of the newly inserted object.

Finally your code will look like below:

```
public ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile)
{
      UserProfileResponse userProfileResponse = new UserProfileResponse();
      int id = createUserProfileData(userProfile)
      userProfileResponse.setId(id) 
      return new ResponseEntity<UserProfileResponse>(userProfileResponse,HTTPStatus.OK);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a value from the RequestBody UserProfile which it didn't contain it actually.Sorry it's impossible.

And we only could receive one requestBody at one time,so we need to use some other ways to collect the info.There is some other solutions:

- Use @PathVariable to get ID from url
- Use @RequestParam to get Id from requestParam
- Add a new field named Id into your UserProfile
- Use other way that that could get your Id,this depend how you persistent or generate the Id.

In your case,I'm not sure what you are going to do with the id.

If the "createUserProfileData" method means you need to offer an id first for persistence.

Well,I dont know which database and what kind of framework you are using.As I know,most of framework and database has the ability to generate the id automatically.But if you insist to generate id by your self,I recommend you UUID.

If the "createUserProfileData" method is saving the UserProfile to the database literally and the id is generated by the database itself,then you just do it and put the Id represent the record you just saved to UserProfileResponse.

As to how to get the id represent the record you just saved?It's up to the framework you're using and precisely how the code is written.